# $response->withRedirect() method in slim not rendering global variable for twig created in middleware

Tags: slim

```
<?php

namespace Auto\middleware;


class registrationMiddleware{
    public $container;

    public function __construct($container){
        $this->container=$container;
        // $container is the $app instance passed from the route

    }

    public function __invoke($request,$response,$next){

       $this->container->getContainer()->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('error','error');
      $response=$next($request,$response);
     return $response->withRedirect($this->container->getContainer()->get('router')->pathFor('redirect'));



  }
}
```

It does not output global variable (error) on rendering.

Comment: If this is a redirect, where do you expect the output to appear? Whole the browser is redirecting? On the subsequent page after the redirect?

Comment: Inside a twig view  like  {{error}}

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant when would you expect to see it in the browser? The "withRedirect" response will tell the browser to immediately load a new URL.

Comment: If i have added a global variable before redirecting i should have the variable available in the view immidiately after loading the url but it is blank on loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to remember that your browser knows nothing about views, and templates, and global variables. All it sees is an HTTP response, which contains a status code, some headers, and *optionally* a body.

A normal response has a status code of 200, and a body containing the content the browser should display.

The Slim `$response->withRedirect` method creates an HTTP response with a status code telling the browser to redirect (301, 302, or 307). Although such a response can contain a body, it will generally just be a fallback for browsers that don't automatically redirect. A standard modern browser will never render this content, because as soon as it sees the status code, it will send a new request to the URL given in the response's `Location` header, and display the content from that to the user *instead*.

Once the user has been redirected, there is no context left over from before the redirect. The browser has requested a new URL, and your application will receive that new request and process it, with no way of seeing what happened previously. There will be no global variables, views, or anything else, left over from before the redirect. The only information retained will be things you've explicitly saved to cookies, or to the session (which is referenced by a cookie).

The end result of all this being that you cannot both display something with a view and issue an HTTP redirect in the same piece of code.

Comment: How does the global twig variable relate with the withRedirect() method it should be available inside the view                                             if we visit a route the the view rendered the global variable  but with the withRedirect() it is not why can you give a explanation with example

Comment: @rsd123 Your browser does not see any global variables; it does not see any templates; it does not know about routes, or views, or Twig, or Slim, or even PHP. So whether the variable is available to Twig is completely irrelevant if that content is never sent to the browser, or if it's sent alongside a status code that says "ignore this content, just redirect here instead".

Comment: But i am setting variable(error) globally to view. I am not passing it with response and the route with redirect rendering other matter present on view but not this global variable. and if i just render the view instead of redirecting it is available and outputting can you explain me with example why is it not outputting on redirecting

Comment: @rsd123 There are **two requests** here: the one which tells the browser to redirect, and the one **after** the browser has redirected. Code that runs in one request - creating views, setting global variables, etc, etc - does not affect the code in the other. If you render the view without redirecting, there is **only one** request.

Comment: @rsd123 Just to clarify one possible confusion, by "two requests", I don't mean different copies of the `$request` object; I mean **completely separate processes running on your server**, caused by the user's browser requesting one URL, and then requesting a different URL.

Comment: Sorry i cant get it. my point is that if variable is avilable globally then after redirecting the view should output the variable on rendering

Comment: @rsd123 "Globally" still only exists inside that one request. Once the response is sent to the browser, telling it to redirect, the global variable is gone, forgotten. PHP starts again on the next request with no "memory" of what happened.

Comment: Thank you very much i got it now

Comment: @rsd123 No worries. If you click the tickmark to "accept" this answer, it will mark the question as "answered" in lists and search results.